# Set Strikethrough Attribute in CFAttributedString

Tags: macos, core-text, core-foundation, nsattributedstring

I am working with a code base that is largely CoreFoundation in C++.  I prefer not to introduce Foundation objects in source files that do not already use them.

I would like to create a CFAttributedString using the NSStrikethroughStyleAttribute without first creating an NSAttributedString.  I know they are toll-free bridged, but I would prefer to keep this source file free of obj-c if possible.

So, is there a way to create a CFAttributedString with the strikethrough attribute without going through Foundation, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming here that this `CFAttributedString` is going to end up being rendered by AppKit eventually. If you're rendering using CoreText, then you're going to have to implement strikethrough yourself, as CoreText doesn't have an attribute for it (there's a [Cocoanetics post](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/) with some sample code).

So, assuming the string is rendered with AppKit by a portion of your app that does use obj-c, then what you really want is to somehow expose just the constant `NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName` to your C code.

The simplest way to do this is probably just to add this to the top of your file:

```
export CFStringRef NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName;
```

Comment: The string is rendered using `CTLineDraw`.  After some experiments, I'm convinced that you're correct.  I had hoped that I would be able to set a `CFAttributedString` using attributes available to `NSAttributedString`, figuring that since they are toll-free bridged this should be possible, and then render with `CTLineDraw`.  However, I think AppKit is able to take advantage of attributed string attributes that direct CoreText rendering cannot.

Comment: @ChristopherCole: Fundamentally, an attributed string is just a string coupled with arbitrary attributes, and the attributes can vary at different points along the string. AppKit defines a set of attributes it knows how to interpret and render. CoreText defines a separate set. If you want, you can define your own custom set of attributes and use them for whatever you want. That's actually what happens in the Cocoanetics post; a custom strikethrough attribute is defined, and the custom drawing routine knows how to find it and interpret it.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I have a better understanding of the purpose of attributed strings and how the attributes are used.

Comment: Just an FYI for anyone looking how to do this in 2022: YES, you can cast a CFAttributeString to a NSAttributeString and set NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName -- and this WORKS -- but ONLY on MacOS 10.12 (Monterey).  When tested on 10.15 (Catalina) and 10.11 (Big Sur), no strikethrough was drawn.